# Why doesn't work Dependency Injection from example?

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I have tried to create DI like [there](https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/the-basics-of-dependency-injection-in-magento-2.html) (Data and DependentClass)
but it doesn't working for me:

> "ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments
> to function DependentClass::__construct(), 0 passed...."

What's wrong?

```
namespace Helper;
class Data
{
    public function HelperDemo()
    {
        var_dump('HelperDemo');
    }
}
```

The calling class

```
namespace Helper;
class DependentClass
{
    private $helper;

    public function __construct(\Helper\Data $helper)
    {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }
    public function MyFunction()
    {
        $this->helper->HelperDemo();
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code file(s) ...

Comment: must be an issue on the constructor of the class that you've extended from the di preference

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in your namespace.

It's starting by Helper (which I doubt it to be your magento root).

Check that you match this structure

`app/code/Xxx/Yyy/Helper/Data`

Then, the namespace should be

namespace Xxx\Yyy\Helper;

Also in your `DependentClass`

The namespace seems to also be Helper which means, you are saying that `DependentClass` is in the same location as your helper `Data`.

If thats the case then in your constructor you can just call `public function __construct(Data $helper)`

If not the you need to full namespace path as mentionned above.

Comment: its just example. I reduced namespace - it start from app..

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the following commands:
php bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Flushing the cache and running the compilation (which you have it twice in your answer, for some reason) should be fine in this case.

Comment: I did it several times in different order